# what is 't Hooft up to?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-gravity, gauge-theory

apart of the 't Hooft diagrams that you all love (and find all sort of dualities starting with them) one of the venues 't Hooft works nowadays is apparently some sort of "deterministic representation of quantum mechanics". I avoid saying "the world is classical" in a broad sense because it is my feeling that this is not what 't Hooft means by what he writes. So, what is 't Hooft up to? 
I tried today to think in terms of number theory about what he says but I ended up with the Universal Coefficient theorem popping into my head. What if some properties of a quantum space in the presence of gravity are best described using some "choice of coefficients" that looks more like classical than like "quantum" looks like at our "energy scale"? I would be very careful in dismissing completely poor 't Hooft just yet...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about evaluating the recent activities of a person rather than any specific physics concept, result, or paper.  It is too broad and it is opinion based.

Comment: yeah, sure it's opinion based... that's how quantum gravity is...

Comment: but feel free to comment if you want so... :)